# What is the interpretation of <>P -> (!P U R)

Tags: model-checking

What is the interpretation of <>P -> (!P U R)? This seems to be contradiction since in future P is expected and checking the absence of P until R.
Model checking tool passes this via BDD as well as BMC techniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any contradiction.

The property is made true by any Buchi automaton s.t.

- P is always false [because the premise of the implication is false], or
- At some point in the future P becomes true, yet for some time P may be false until R becomes true.

**i.e.**

[image]

In natural language, one would express that property as follows: *"If, by any chance, sooner or later P becomes true, then it must be the case that the 'event' R fired first"*.

For instance, you can imagine P be *"sending answer message"* and R be *"received  input message"* and the whole property be *"no unsolicited answer message is ever sent"*.